# Cron periodicity works unclear with month days

Tags: cron

I have expression `0 0 6/2 * *`

it will run anything every second day starting from 6 day of month and in next month it can be earlier than 6 day? *Example cron runs:*

```
2022-06-06
2022-06-08
2022-06-10
...
2022-06-26
2022-06-28
2022-06-30
2022-07-02
2022-07-04
2022-07-06
2022-07-08
...
```

Does it work like this or cron run only from 6 day every month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://crontab.cronhub.io/)

> At 12:00 AM, every 2 days, starting on day 6 of the month

So *no*, it will start on 6th day of month and then every 2 days